# Display price value after dropdown change in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to create a dropdown that is populated by values from MySQL DB.
In DB I have defined time - price values.

Example from SQL table

```
-----------------------
| id  | time | price |
-----------------------
|  1  |13:00 |    6  | 
|  2  |14:00 |   12  |
|  3  |15:00 |   18  |
|  4  |16:00 |   24  |
-----------------------
```

The goal is when I choose a specific time, the price will be displayed.

I have managed to get the dropdown working with time values, but how to get a price from the table as to be displayed.

So, if I choose time to be `15:00`I would like that price value is displayed under the dropdown menu.

Here is a code snippet from JSP page (index.jsp):

```
<form>
Select time:
<select>
<c:forEach items = "${LIST}" var = "list">
<option value = "${list.time}">${list.time}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Confirm">
</form>
```

Dropdown values, getting values from DB (model class is used as well, not displayed in this example):

```
public List<model> list() throws Exception{
        
        List<model> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRes = null;
        
        try {
            
            //get connection
            
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();
            
            //create sql query in string
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM price_time_data ORDER BY id";
            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            
            //execute statement
            myRes = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
            
            //Process results from query
            
            while(myRes.next()) {
                //retrieve row by row
                int id = myRes.getInt("id");
                String time = myRes.getString("time");
                String price = myRes.getString("price");
                
                //create list object
                
                model tempModel = new model(id, time, price);
                
                //add it to  list
                
                list.add(tempModel);
                System.out.println("Success!!!!");
            }
            
            return list;
            
            
        } finally {
            //close JDBC object
            close(myConn, myStmt, myRes);
        }
```

Passing values to JSP via servlet (doGet):

```
// get values from db util
        
        List<model> list = DataBaseDAO.list();
        
        // add values to the report
        
        request.setAttribute("LIST", list);
                
        
        // send values to JSP page
        
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

For submission, I will need price and time values, but I can get that from the table directly. Live onchange price display would be more user friendly.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.